# Implementing word dropout in pytorch

Tags: pytorch, dropout

I want to add word dropout to my network so that I can have sufficient training examples for training the embedding of the "unk" token. As far as I'm aware, this is standard practice. Let's assume the index of the unk token is 0, and the index for padding is 1 (we can switch them if that's more convenient).

This is a simple CNN network which implements word dropout the way I would have expected it to work:

```
class Classifier(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, params):
        super(Classifier, self).__init__()
        self.params = params
        self.word_dropout = nn.Dropout(params["word_dropout"])
        self.pad = torch.nn.ConstantPad1d(max(params["window_sizes"])-1, 1)
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(params["vocab_size"], params["word_dim"], padding_idx=1)
        self.convs = nn.ModuleList([nn.Conv1d(1, params["feature_num"], params["word_dim"] * window_size, stride=params["word_dim"], bias=False) for window_size in params["window_sizes"]])
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(params["dropout"])
        self.fc = nn.Linear(params["feature_num"] * len(params["window_sizes"]), params["num_classes"])

    def forward(self, x, l):
        x = self.word_dropout(x)
        x = self.pad(x)
        embedded_x = self.embedding(x)
        embedded_x = embedded_x.view(-1, 1, x.size()[1] * self.params["word_dim"]) # [batch_size, 1, seq_len * word_dim]
        features = [F.relu(conv(embedded_x)) for conv in self.convs]
        pooled = [F.max_pool1d(feat, feat.size()[2]).view(-1, params["feature_num"]) for feat in features]
        pooled = torch.cat(pooled, 1)
        pooled = self.dropout(pooled)
        logit = self.fc(pooled)
        return logit
```

Don't mind the padding - pytorch doesn't have an easy way of using non zero padding in CNNs, much less trainable non-zero padding, so I'm doing it manually. Dropout also doesn't allow me to use non zero dropout, and I want to separate the padding token from the unk token. I'm keeping it in my example because it's the reason for this question's existence.

This doesn't work because dropout wants Float Tensors so that it can scale them properly, while my input is Long Tensors that don't need to be scaled.

Is there an easy way of doing this in pytorch? I essentially want to use LongTensor-friendly dropout (bonus: better if it will let me specify a dropout constant that isn't 0, so that I could use zero padding).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I would do it outside of your model, before converting your input into a `LongTensor`.

This would look like this:

```py
import random

def add_unk(input_token_id, p):
    #random.random() gives you a value between 0 and 1
    #to avoid switching your padding to 0 we add 'input_token_id > 1'
    if random.random() < p and input_token_id > 1:
        return 0
    else:
        return input_token_id

#than you have your input token_id
#for this example I take just a random number, lets say 127
input_token_id = 127

#let p be your probability for UNK
p = 0.01

your_input_tensor = torch.LongTensor([add_unk(input_token_id, p)])
```

**Edit:**

So there are two options which come to my mind which are actually GPU-friendly. In general both solutions should be much more efficient.

**Option one - Doing computation directly in** `forward()`**:**

If you're not using `torch.utils` and don't have plans using it later this is probably the way to go.

Instead of doing the computation before we just do it in the `forward()` method of main PyTorch class. However I see no (simple) way doing this in `torch 0.3.1.`, so you would need to upgrade to version `0.4.0`:

So imagine `x` is your input vector:

```py
>>> x = torch.tensor(range(10))
>>> x
tensor([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9])
```

`probs` is a vector containing uniform probabilities for dropout so we can check later agains our probability for dropout:

```py
>>> probs = torch.empty(10).uniform_(0, 1)
>>> probs
tensor([ 0.9793,  0.1742,  0.0904,  0.8735,  0.4774,  0.2329,  0.0074,
         0.5398,  0.4681,  0.5314])
```

Now we apply the dropout probabilities `probs` on our input `x`:

```py
>>> torch.where(probs > 0.2, x, torch.zeros(10, dtype=torch.int64))
tensor([ 0,  0,  0,  3,  4,  5,  0,  7,  8,  9])
```

*Note: To see some effect I chose a dropout probability of 0.2 here. I reality you probably want it to be smaller.*

You can pick for this any token / id you like, here is an example with `42` as unknown token id:

```py
>>> unk_token = 42
>>> torch.where(probs > 0.2, x, torch.empty(10, dtype=torch.int64).fill_(unk_token))
tensor([  0,  42,  42,   3,   4,   5,  42,   7,   8,   9])
```

`torch.where` comes with `PyTorch 0.4.0`:
https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html#torch.where

I don't know about the shapes of your network, but your `forward()` should look something like this then (when using mini-batching you need to flatten the input before applying dropout):

```py
def forward_train(self, x, l):
    # probabilities
    probs = torch.empty(x.size(0)).uniform_(0, 1)
    # applying word dropout
    x = torch.where(probs > 0.02, x, torch.zeros(x.size(0), dtype=torch.int64))

    # continue like before ...
    x = self.pad(x)
    embedded_x = self.embedding(x)
    embedded_x = embedded_x.view(-1, 1, x.size()[1] * self.params["word_dim"]) # [batch_size, 1, seq_len * word_dim]
    features = [F.relu(conv(embedded_x)) for conv in self.convs]
    pooled = [F.max_pool1d(feat, feat.size()[2]).view(-1, params["feature_num"]) for feat in features]
    pooled = torch.cat(pooled, 1)
    pooled = self.dropout(pooled)
    logit = self.fc(pooled)
    return logit
```

*Note: I named the function `forward_train()` so you should use another `forward()` without dropout for evaluation / predicting. But you could also use some `if conditions` with `train()`.*

**Option two: using** `torch.utils.data.Dataset`**:**

If you're using `Dataset` provided by `torch.utils` it is very easy to do this kind of pre-processing efficiently. `Dataset` uses strong multi-processing acceleration by default so the the code sample above just has to be executed in the `__getitem__` method of your `Dataset` class.

This could look like this:

```py
def __getitem__(self, index):
    'Generates one sample of data'
    # Select sample
    ID = self.input_tokens[index]

    # Load data and get label
    # using add ink_unk function from code above
    X = torch.LongTensor(add_unk(ID, p=0.01))
    y = self.targets[index]

    return X, y
```

This is a bit out of context and doesn't look very elegant but I think you get the idea. According to this [blog post of Shervine Amidi at Stanford](https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/pytorch-how-to-generate-data-parallel.html) it should be no problem to do more complex pre-processing steps in this function:

> Since our code [`Dataset` is meant] is designed to be multicore-friendly, note that you
>   can do more complex operations instead (e.g. computations from source
>   files) without worrying that data generation becomes a bottleneck in
>   the training process.

The linked blog post - ["A detailed example of how to generate your data in parallel with PyTorch"](https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/pytorch-how-to-generate-data-parallel.html) - provides also a good guide for implementing the data generation with `Dataset` and `DataLoader`.

I guess you'll prefer option one - only two lines and it should be very efficient. :)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. This solution feels out of necessity to me, though... As the word dropout needs to be separately calculated for every batch and can't be reused, it makes more sense to perform word dropout on the tensor which is GPU accelerated, compared to this solution which is inefficient. Tensorflow can do this, I believe

Comment: Are you still interested in this? If so, I think can provide you a GPU friendly solution. Btw. 'separately calculated for every batch and can't be reused' - I would not calculate it only once, you should re-calculate it for every epoch, this lets you make better use of your data. The model can make use of words dropped out in epoch n in epoch n+1, when the dropped out words are different.

Comment: For now I've implemented the preprocessing solution so I accepted your answer, if you have a GPU solution of course it'll be way better :)

Comment: okay - I updated the answer, I think option one should be what you were looking for :)